# Need script to get information from instagram

Tags: web-scraping, instagram

My wife is an artist and is doing a collaboration with a couple other artists. As part of it they are doing a giveaway, to enter one must be following all three of them on instagram, like the post, and comment on it.

Rather than compare everyone manually I'd like to see if there is a tool that already exist that can grab this info. I've not written anything that scrapes info from instagram myself but I could try to whip something up quickly if there isn't already an existing tool.

Recommendations for tools or APIs if I need to build it myself is appreciated.

Comment: Instagram has 2 types of free APIs: Basic Display API, and the Graph API. Basic Display can only fetch images posted on your profile, grosso modo, so you will need Graph API. It's a bit more convoluted because I think you need to validade your API application with Instagram. But it's way cleaner than using Selenium to scrape the profile IMHO.

Comment: I've stumbled across instaloader for python that might do the trick. Are you familiar with it @Niloct ?

Comment: I was not :) I just tried it, it's very nice indeed, but has a major drawback which you won't find on the API track: small rate limit. Look what I've got after downloading 155 posts from a test profile: `Too many queries in the last time. Need to wait 644 seconds, until 16:29.`

Comment: If you issue the command with the `--login` option, it seems that the rate limit is waived. I am trying to download instagram comments now.

Comment: It works for your needs. Are you using Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Niloct Windows. Python is what I've been using most for work lately too and it what I have setup on my personal machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Python package you've mentioned is very useful, and combined with text tools on Windows, can make you find all comments on your wife's Instagram profile.

Assuming you have the latest Python installed, you can install and run `instaloader` Python package on a Windows machine like this, on command prompt:

```
C:\Users\test> pip install instaloader
C:\Users\test> instaloader --login [your_instagram_account] --comments [insta_data_profile]
```

Replace `[your_instagram_account]` with an Instagram account which login password you know, and `[insta_data_profile]` with your wife's profile ID (i.e., the `@profile`). The reason you need to log in is to ensure no low rate limits will be applied on your data download.

You will be asked for your password. The session info will be stored under your home directory, in a `\AppData\Local\Instaloader` subdirectory, so you can delete this folder later.

So, in the directory in which you called `instaloader` on command prompt, a subdirectory will be created with the Instagram profile name. Inside it, you will find all posts, media, and comments on that profile.

Comments will be stored like this:

```
C:\Users\test\profile> dir

01/01/2024  11:59 PM             2,147 2023-12-14_17-14-45_UTC_comments.json
01/01/2024  11:59 PM             2,147 2023-12-14_17-14-45_UTC_comments.json
```

And then, finally, you can query all this text data with tools like `findstr`:

```
C:\Users\test\profile> findstr /l @ *comments*
```

(This will show tagged Instagram users (i.e., text that begins with `@`) in all comments on downloaded data).